# Proving $\lim_{x\to \infty}(a_n + b_n)=\lim_{x\to \infty}(a_n) + \lim_{x\to \infty}(b_n)$ for convergent sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

The following is the proof of the limit law that says that for two convergent sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$,
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(a_n + b_n)=\lim_{x\to \infty}(a_n) + \lim_{x\to \infty}(b_n)$$

I would appreciate if someone could tell me if the proof is correct. The proof is as follows.

Proof: Note that addition for the real numbers is associative. Thus, the sequence
$$(a_n + b_n)_{n=m}^{\infty} = (a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty} + (b_n)_{n=m}^{\infty}$$
Given that $(a_n)_{n=m}^{\infty} = x$ and $(b_n)_{n=m}^{\infty} = y$, we have that $(a_n +b_n)_{n=m}^{\infty} = x + y$. Hence,
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(a_n + b_n)= \lim_{x\to \infty}(a_n) + \lim_{x\to \infty}(b_n)$$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: "Note that for all $u,v,w\in\Bbb R$, $(u+v)+w=u+(v+w)$": duly noted; what has that to do with all the rest?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I wrote that because If we look at the individual elements of the sequence, it doesn’t matter when we group the terms or not. This allows us to write the sequence as individual sequences. Am thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Although if is finitely associative you need to prove that it is ok to subtract the limits

Comment: The proof is not correct. In the last step you simply state what you want to prove as a fact. Note that you never use the definition of a limit, nor do you explicitly use some property of limits, which indicates the proof cannot work.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite If I’m not wrong, we write the limit symbol when a sequence converges. I do use the fact that both sequences converge as it is given in the question that they converge.

Comment: Can you define what it means for a sequence to converge? Otherwise you cannot prove this result. See the answer below for a correct proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what level of rigour you are going for, but here is a pretty standard proof that the limit of sums is equal to the sum of limits (provided everything converges). Assume that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=A$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=B$$

We seek to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)=A+B$$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. By definition, there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N_1$ implies

$$|a_n-A|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

In a similar vein, there exists $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N_2$ implies

$$|b_n-B|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Define $N=\text{max}(N_1,N_2)$. For $n\geq N$ we have

$$|(a_n+b_n)-(A+B)|=|(a_n-A)+(b_n-B)|\leq |a_n-A|+|b_n-B|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

and we are done.